# ruby on rails form, First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie to ruby on rails.... here i want to add the data captured from from to mysql database.i have the from in user_dashboard.html.erb file.

user_dashboard.html.erb

```
      <%= form_for @new_product, :url => { :action => "add" }  do |f|  %>
          <%= f.text_field  :product_name %>
          <%= f.text_field  :product_price %>
          <%= f.submit "Add product", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%end%>
```

but when this renders in browser. i am getting error....
How can i get rid of this error?

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@new_product` is `nil`, set it in your controller.

Comment: Will it work if i define it in the PagesController??

Comment: @MithunRaikar it depends. Which controller does this view belong to?

Comment: Because i have not created any controllers.... i have generated the pages, and there are pages controllers... and this form is in user_dashboard.html.erb page.. and also there is 

  def user_dashboard
  end
in pages controller